# Insert a formula from another sheet based on same cell values

Tags: excel

I have a master workbook with two columns: names and formulas, which are specific for certain names. Generally, there are some 300 different names and 10 different formulas. What I need is to insert that formula in another sheet when some of this names appear - some kind of vlookup formula which won't give me value but formula.

And second part of a problem is how to make this formula (if it can be somehow inserted) dynamic and use relative values for calculation from same row in calculation sheet....

Answer (score 0):

Please see my simulation below. My formula is `F3` (ignored `=` sign) and its name is `Name1`.  For test purpose, I typed 7 into cell `F3` and 8 into cell `F4`.

[image]

With the formula below I typed in sheet2, I am able to call the formula of `=F3` and change the reference given to cell F3 to F4 and reach to result of 8 in master sheet.

`=INDIRECT("Master!"&SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP("Name1",Master!$I$3:$J$10,2,FALSE),"3","4"))`

Maybe you can solve your puzzle by using functions I used in above simulation (`INDIRECT` and `SUBSTITUTE`).

Comment: Goran, theoretically this is what you want but the formula I used is too simple.  You may have difficulties adopting your real formulas to solve in this way.  If you give extra explanations on what you are trying to do, I can maybe recommend different and more effective solutions (i.e. building our own functions).